# UPDATED - Kotlin - Extracting data from SQLite to a .txt file, the file is created but its empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite

I am new to Kotlin and i am making a small app in which the user will be able to insert his contacts one by one along with some more details for each contact.
After inserting all or most of his contacts, he will be able to export data into a .txt file, and each line of the txt file will be the details for each contact (in a very specific format, each field will be separated with a ";").

After exiting the app, the user will be able to insert the same file, and all his contacts will be re-inserted into the Database (SQLite), so that he can continue from where he left off.

For now i have already implemented most of the utilities of the app (inserting contacts into SQLite, fetching contacts and showing them with a recyclerView, etc) and all that its left is exporting and re-inserting data through the txt file.

I have already made an intent so that i can open the native directory chooser of android, create a file where the user wants and then writing in the file, but after executing it, the file is empty.
I want to save the file externally (downloads folder) so that the user will be able to open it on his own (through a text file reader or through one of the other apps - mostly desktop - that i have already made)

I have already tested if the string builder works and he outputs almost exactly what i want (i would ideally like to remove the square brackets from the start and end of the final result and also place each line of contacts in a new line, and separate each line with "/n" and not with ",")

This is my Data Class Object:

```
package com.example.contactsform.model

data class ContactModelClass(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val surname: String,
    val dateOfBirth: String,
    val phoneNumber: String,
    val email: String,
    val address: String,
    val city: String,
    val notes: String)

{
    override fun toString() : String {
        val fields = listOf(
            this.id.toString(),
            this.name,
            this.surname,
            this.dateOfBirth,
            this.phoneNumber,
            this.email,
            this.address,
            this.city,
            this.notes)

            return fields.reduce{ field , element -> "$field;$element" }
    }
}
```

This is one of my Activities (where the extracting data button is placed) :

```
package com.example.contactsform.activityViews

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.contactsform.model.ContactModelClass
import com.example.contactsform.adapter.ItemAdapter
import com.example.contactsform.R
import com.example.contactsform.databaseHelper.SQLiteHelper
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException


class ContactListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private  lateinit var contactsRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var addContactButton : Button
    private lateinit var exportDataButton: Button

    private val filePicker = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result->
        val data : Intent? = result.data
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            val selectedFileUri = data.data
               if (selectedFileUri != null) {
                   val selectedFilePath = selectedFileUri.toString()
                    writeTextToFile(this, selectedFilePath, dataToWriteInFile())
               }
            }

    }

    private val FILENAME = "ExportedContacts.txt"


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list)

        contactsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.contactsRecyclerView)

        setupListOfDataIntoRecyclerView()


        addContactButton= findViewById(R.id.addContactButton)
        addContactButton.setOnClickListener {
            val changeFormIntent = Intent(this, AddContactActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(changeFormIntent)
        }

        exportDataButton = findViewById(R.id.exportDataButton)
        exportDataButton.setOnClickListener {
            createContactFile()

         }

    }


    private fun createContactFile() {
        val openDirectoryPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
            openDirectoryPickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            openDirectoryPickerIntent.type = "text/plain"
            openDirectoryPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, FILENAME)
        filePicker.launch(openDirectoryPickerIntent)
    }


    private fun dataToWriteInFile(): String {

        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        return stringBuilder.appendLine(getContactsList().toString()).toString()

    }


    private fun writeTextToFile(context: Context, filePath: String ,dataToFile: String) {
        val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filePath)

        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            fileOutputStream.use{stream->
                stream.write(dataToFile.toByteArray())
            }

         }catch (e: IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    private fun setupListOfDataIntoRecyclerView() {
        if (getContactsList().size > 0){
            contactsRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            contactsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

            val itemAdapter = ItemAdapter(this, getContactsList())
            contactsRecyclerView.adapter = itemAdapter


        } else {
            contactsRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE


        }
    }

    private fun getContactsList(): ArrayList<ContactModelClass> {
        val sqliteHelper = SQLiteHelper(this)
        return  sqliteHelper.loadContacts()

    }

}
```

This is my databaseHelper :

```
package com.example.contactsform.databaseHelper

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import com.example.contactsform.model.ContactModelClass
import java.util.ArrayList

class SQLiteHelper (context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context , DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "contacts_form"
        private const val TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts"

        private const val ID = "ID"
        private const val NAME = "Name"
        private const val SURNAME = "Surname"
        private const val DATE_OF_BIRTH = "Date_Of_Birth"
        private const val PHONE_NUMBER = "Phone_Number"
        private const val EMAIL = "Email"
        private const val ADDRESS = "Address"
        private const val CITY = "City"
        private const val NOTES = "Notes"
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + NAME + " TEXT,"
                + SURNAME + " TEXT,"
                + DATE_OF_BIRTH + " TEXT,"
                + PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
                + EMAIL + " TEXT,"
                + ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + CITY + " TEXT,"
                + NOTES + " TEXT)")
        db?.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_CONTACTS")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun insertContact (contact : ContactModelClass) : Long {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        var contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(NAME, contact.name)
        contentValues.put(SURNAME, contact.surname)
        contentValues.put(DATE_OF_BIRTH, contact.dateOfBirth)
        contentValues.put(PHONE_NUMBER, contact.phoneNumber)
        contentValues.put(EMAIL, contact.email)
        contentValues.put(ADDRESS, contact.address)
        contentValues.put(CITY, contact.city)
        contentValues.put(NOTES, contact.notes)

       val success = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)

       db.close()

        return success
    }

    fun loadContacts() : ArrayList<ContactModelClass> {

        val contactList : ArrayList<ContactModelClass> = ArrayList<ContactModelClass>()

        val selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE_CONTACTS"

        val db = this.readableDatabase
        var cursor: Cursor? = null

        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

        } catch (e: SQLiteException){
            db.execSQL(selectQuery)
            return ArrayList()
        }

        var id: Int
        var name: String
        var surname : String
        var dateOfBirth: String
        var phoneNumber: String
        var email: String
        var address: String
        var city: String
        var notes: String

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ID))
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NAME))
                surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SURNAME))
                dateOfBirth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DATE_OF_BIRTH))
                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PHONE_NUMBER))
                email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(EMAIL))
                address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ADDRESS))
                city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CITY))
                notes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NOTES))

                val contact = ContactModelClass(
                    id = id,
                    name = name,
                    surname = surname,
                    dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth,
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber,
                    email = email, address = address,
                    city = city,
                    notes = notes)

                contactList.add(contact)

            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }

        return contactList

    }

    fun deleteContactsTable() {
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        db?.execSQL("DROP TABLE $TABLE_CONTACTS")
        onCreate(db)
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I updated the Activity but still the file is created but is empty (code below)

```
class ContactListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val createFile = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ it ->
        val resultData : Intent? = it.data
        val selectedFileUri = resultData?.data
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try{
                if (resultData != null) {
                    resultData.data?.let {
                        if (selectedFileUri != null) {
                            contentResolver.openOutputStream(selectedFileUri).use { stream ->
                                stream?.writer()?.write(dataToWriteInFile())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    } catch (e: IOException){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
        }
    }
 private val FILENAME = "ExportedContacts.txt"


------------------------------------------------------------

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list)

exportDataButton = findViewById(R.id.exportDataButton)
        exportDataButton.setOnClickListener {
        createContactFile()
        }
}


------------------------------------------------------------
private fun createContactFile() {
        val openDirectoryPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply{
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, FILENAME)
        }
        createFile.launch(openDirectoryPickerIntent)
}


 private fun dataToWriteInFile(): String {

        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        return stringBuilder.appendLine(getContactsList().toString()).toString()

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write your content to the location requested via `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`? Or are you trying to write your content to a file in `getExternalFilesDir()`? Right now, you are doing a bit of both, and that is not going to work. You need to pick **one** of those two approaches. Which do you want?

Comment: from a quick look perhaps try to use the FileOutputStream's `close` method https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/io/FileOutputStream#close

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem, i want to use the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT because i think i understand how the user will be able to choose where the file will be saved. If i remove the whole `val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filePath)` how should i the whole writing in file?

Comment: @MikeT Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem, i just added the `fileOutputStream.close()` but unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: "If i remove the whole... how should i the whole writing in file?" -- call `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `OutputStream` that you can use. I cover this subject and this specific approach in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Room/pages/chap-backup-001.html) of [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Room/).

Comment: @CommonsWare can i do in with SQLite db and not Room?

Comment: Um, well, Room is backed by SQLite, so I am uncertain what difference you are seeing.

Comment: @CommonsWare i updated the post, could you see it again and tell me you opinion?

Comment: It certainly looks more promising. See if you are getting an exception in Logcat. Use breakpoints or logging to see if `dataToWriteInFile()` is returning what you expect. Use Device File Explorer in Android Studio or `adb pull` to examine the contents that you wrote (if you're using something else).

Comment: @CommonsWare yesterday i noticed in Logcat yesterday i noticed that after i am clicking for the first time the "Export Data" button it said System / W : A resource failed to call close and System / W : A resource failed to call AbstractCursor.close.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that an issue is the use of:-

```
val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filePath)
```

When tested (code used for testing below) this results in a file not found trapped exception (so the code continued). Using Device Explorer the directory (noting that  mkdirs was added even though apparently not required) existed but not the file after returning from the call to the writeTextFile.

Changing to instead use:-

```
val file = File(/*context.getExternalFilesDir(null),*/ filePath)
```

Happily went ahead and created the file which was then visible, could be opened, and the data viewed, via Device Explorer.

**Note** the testing undertaken was with a cut down version, purely to check the writeTextToFile method and to ascertain issues if any. The code used for testing:-

- Unchaged SQLiteHelper and ContactModel classes
- the following activity code, amended to test the writeTextToFile function as per

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val filePicker =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                val selectedFileUri = data.data
                if (selectedFileUri != null) {
                    val selectedFilePath = selectedFileUri.toString()
                    writeTextToFile(this, selectedFilePath, dataToWriteInFile())
                }
            }

        }

    private val FILENAME = "ExportedContacts.txt"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val extFilePath = this.getExternalFilesDir("testing")
        var filePath: File? = null
        val fileName: String = "testit.txt"
        if (extFilePath != null) {
            extFilePath.mkdirs()
            filePath = File("${extFilePath}${File.separator}${fileName}")
        }
        val helper = SQLiteHelper(this)
        helper.insertContact(ContactModelClass(1,"A","Z","2000-01-01","00 0000 0001","a@email","1 Nowhere Street.","ELSEWHERE","not much to say"))
        helper.insertContact(ContactModelClass(2,"B","Z","2000-02-01","00 0000 0002","b@email","1 Nowhere Street.","ELSEWHERE","not much to say"))
        helper.insertContact(ContactModelClass(3,"C","Z","2000-03-01","00 0000 0003","c@email","1 Nowhere Street.","ELSEWHERE","not much to say"))
        helper.insertContact(ContactModelClass(4,"D","Z","2000-04-01","00 0000 0004","d@email","1 Nowhere Street.","ELSEWHERE","not much to say"))
        if (filePath != null) {
            writeTextToFile(this,filePath.path,dataToWriteInFile())
        }
        val breakpoint: String = ""
    }

    private fun createContactFile() {
        val openDirectoryPickerIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
        openDirectoryPickerIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        openDirectoryPickerIntent.type = "text/plain"
        openDirectoryPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, FILENAME)
        filePicker.launch(openDirectoryPickerIntent)
    }


    private fun dataToWriteInFile(): String {
        val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
        return stringBuilder.appendLine(getContactsList().toString()).toString()
    }

    private fun writeTextToFile(context: Context, filePath: String, dataToFile: String) {
        val file = File(/*context.getExternalFilesDir(null),*/ filePath)
        try {
            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
            val dataAsByteArray = dataToFile.toByteArray()
            val breakpoint: String = ""
            fileOutputStream.use { stream ->
                stream.write(dataToFile.toByteArray())
            }
            fileOutputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun getContactsList(): ArrayList<ContactModelClass> {
        val sqliteHelper = SQLiteHelper(this)
        return sqliteHelper.loadContacts()
    }
}
```

- i.e. the UI aspect has been cut of the equation/test and everything done is done on the main thread.

The end result, a file containing:-

```
[1;A;Z;2000-01-01;00 0000 0001;a@email;1 Nowhere Street.;ELSEWHERE;not much to say, 2;B;Z;2000-02-01;00 0000 0002;b@email;1 Nowhere Street.;ELSEWHERE;not much to say, 3;C;Z;2000-03-01;00 0000 0003;c@email;1 Nowhere Street.;ELSEWHERE;not much to say, 4;D;Z;2000-04-01;00 0000 0004;d@email;1 Nowhere Street.;ELSEWHERE;not much to say]
```

However, if the code is changed to use the original setting of the **file**, then after placing a breakpoint on the line `val breakpoint: String = ""` in the `onCreate` function:-

[image]

Then running (after uninstalling the App id it has been installed) and clicking the debug (green Bug Icon) the following are the results:-

1. [image]

   1. looks OK????
2. In the log `W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/a.a.so77247817kotlinsqlitewritetofile/files/storage/emulated/0/Android/data ....`

   1. OOOPS
3. Using Device Explorer and following the path:-

   1. [image]
   2. The expectation would be that the actual file would exist in the testing directory, it does not.
   3. As shown above in the working code, the file exists and can be opened.

**You still may need to heed the comments applied to the question**, although the suggested close has been included in the writeTestToFile function.

Comment: i did remove the `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` as suggested, and also removed the whole intent that opens the native file picker `private fun createContactFile()` that seemed you didn't need to use. i tried to run the app again with and without debugging but to be honest firstly i couldn't see any new file created (that may be a problem from my part because i tried to understand what you changed and where i should place the changes) , secondly i dont know if the new file created is in the external storage and thirdly i want to let the user choose where he wants to save the file